# Entity Framework LINQ query construction

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm learning EF and LINQ while working on an API for a project
While in most case EF and LINQ made my coding easier this specific case is different.

I have a list of integers and i have to query my DB including all int inside 
the list [10,2,23]

```
var queryable = (from p in db.plants 
                           where p.plant_id == 10
                              || p.plant_id == 2
                              || p.plant_id == 23
                           select p)
                 .ToList();
```

but the list is created at runtime and the number of items inside is variable
 so what's the method to use for creating the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Contains()` function on an `IEnumerable` of your required ids. Entity Framework will convert this to a SQL `IN` clause so that it is an nice efficient query.

So this would lead your example to be:

```
var plantIds = new List<int> {10, 2, 23};
var queryable = (from p in db.plants
                 where plantIds.Contains(p.plant_id)
                 select p)
                .ToList();
```